# How to delete/unschedule scheduled updates for product programatically in Magento 2 commerce edition?

Tags: magento-2-commerce, content-staging

I have added a scheduled update for a product as shown below

[image]

Now I want to delete this schedule programatically. How to achieve that?

I see the product staging class `Magento\CatalogStaging\Api\ProductStagingInterface` which has a function `unschedule($product, $version)`

Where I can get the information about the version of a specific product which needs to be passed to this function?

I have used below code as an example to unscedule.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomImport\Model;

class Test
{
   
    protected $productStaging;
    protected $productRepository;
 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductStaging $productStaging,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
       
    ) {
        $this->productStaging = $productStaging;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function deleteSchedule()
    {
    try {
        $product = $this->productRepository->get('24-WG089', true);
        $version = 1628165040;
        $this->productStaging->unschedule($product, $version);
    }   catch (\Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
}
```

I have taken `$version` from catalog_product_entity table `created_in` field. After executing above code, product itself gets removed from catalog and cannot be found in admin. Though I can see records for that product in catalog_product_entity table.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Below is the method which can be used to delete future scheduled updates.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomImport\Model\Import;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Staging\Model\Entity\Upcoming\SearchResultFactory;
use Magento\Staging\Api\UpdateRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManagerFactory;
use Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductStaging;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Test
{

    protected $request;
    protected $searchResultFactory;
    protected $datetimeFormatter;
    protected $updateRepository;
    protected $versionManager;
    protected $productStaging;
    protected $productRepository;


    public function __construct (
        RequestInterface $request,
        SearchResultFactory $searchResultFactory,
        DateTime  $dateTime,
        UpdateRepositoryInterface $updateRepository,
        VersionManagerFactory $versionManagerFactory,
        ProductStaging $productStaging,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->searchResultFactory = $searchResultFactory;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->updateRepository = $updateRepository;
        $this->versionManager = $versionManagerFactory->create();
        $this->productStaging = $productStaging;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getSchedule($productId)
    {
        $schedules = [];
        try {
            $params = [
                'entityRequestName' => 'id',
                'entityTable' => 'catalog_product_entity',
                'entityColumn' => 'entity_id'
            ];
            $this->request->setParams( ['id' => $productId]);
            $schedules = $this->searchResultFactory->create($params);
        }   catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        return  $schedules;
    }

    public function deleteSchedule($productId, $productSku) {
        if ($schedules = $this->getSchedule($productId)) {
            foreach ($schedules as $schedule) {
                try {
                    $scheduleStartTime = $schedule->getStartTime();
                    $currentGmtTime = $this->dateTime->gmtDate(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT);
                    if ($scheduleStartTime <= $currentGmtTime) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $existingSchedule = $this->updateRepository->get($schedule->getId());
                    $updatedIn = $schedule->getId();
                    $this->versionManager->setCurrentVersionId($updatedIn);
                    $product = $this->productRepository->get($productSku);
                    $this->updateRepository->delete($existingSchedule);
                    $this->productStaging->unschedule($product, $this->versionManager->getVersion()->getId());
                    echo 'deleted';
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->getLogger()->info('sku '. $productSku . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you need to pass product id and sku to deleteSchedule() function (example: `deleteSchedule(19, 'test')`) and it will delete the future schedules of that particular product.

Comment: Any working module or code snippets ?

Answer (score 1):

The interface you mentioned is correct, but there is much more useful information inside the model `Magento\CatalogStaging\Model\ProductStaging`.

In that model, we see the function `unschedule()` defined as:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
 * @param string $version
 * @return bool
 */
public function unschedule(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $version)
{
    return (bool)$this->entityManager->delete(
        $product,
        [
            'store_id' => $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId(),
            'created_in' => $version
        ]
    );
}
```

After looking at my own instance, I see that all the `created_at` values in the database are set to 1, I don't personally use the schedule update feature but it would seem that you would add 1 to the version when running `schedule()`.

I would recommend you open the model/controller for the scheduled updates page and see if you can get any more information about how the versioning system works from there next.

Edit:
Another file that seems to get closer to the answer you are looking for is `Magento\Staging\Model\Entity\Update\Action\Delete\RemoveAction`.

In it, it passes `$this->versionManager->getVersion()->getId()` as the version where versionManager is a `Magento\Staging\Model\VersionManager`.

Comment: created_in field is 1 when product is created for the first time. If a schedule is added new entry happens in catalog_product_entity table with different created_in value which is supposed to be version number which can be seen in staging_update table. After running the unschedule function with version number deletes the product itself. Added details in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I understand it better now

Comment: does any one find fix for this? any patches ?